# Is it obvious that this integral converges given the following assumptions?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, information-theory

The integral is $\int\limits_{p(x) > 0}p^{-\lambda + 1}(x) \, \left| \ln p(x) \right|^k \, dx$.

Assumptions:

- $\lambda > 0, k > 0$
- $\int\limits_{p(x) > 0}p^{-\lambda + 1}(x) \, dx < \infty$
- $p$ is a probability density function satisfying $\int p(x) \, dx = 1$.

This comes from the first few paragraphs in this paper on a topic in information theory -- http://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.3661.pdf (see eq. 2.4), which states that "it is not hard to see that ..." The paper explains the exact context in a few lines around eq. 2.1-2.5. The claim doesn't seem obvious to me. In fact, I am not 100% confident it is even always true. Perhaps I'm missing an obvious connection that makes this clear ... ***Please view the specified portion of the reference before attempting to answer.***

Comment: *Ahem* In case you've ever wondered what was going through an author's head when they decided a particular claim was obvious and left the proof to the reader: http://abstrusegoose.com/12

Comment: I think I can actually prove the claim false ... I'll hold off though - I'd need to work it out more carefully. Hoping someone else can weigh in ...

Comment: After see 4.54 I think it was for him lol

Comment: Why should we have to look at that paper? Why not state all assumptions here, clearly and precisely?

Comment: @zhw, I edited my question to state the assumption as clearly as I could. I could have still made a mistake. Moreover, there is still the contention that the claim is likely correct if the correct assumptions are considered. Given that this contention is plausible, I think it's reasonable for someone to look at the relevant portion of the paper, which is literally no more than a few lines and a few equations (in the beginning of II). Someone might then detect if I misunderstood the assumptions. The rest of the paper is not relevant to this question. Moreover, I am offering a bounty in exchange

Comment: But that paper in the first few lines has a bunch of strange terminology. Do you agree that the example I gave  is a valid counterexample with the question as you now have it?

Comment: @zhw yes, and I upvoted that answer. I don't think you would need the first few lines of the paper. You only need the beginning of section II up to the line immediately prior to equation 2.5 (literally 6-7 lines), which has no undefined terms as far as I can tell. H(X) is the Shannon Entropy of the random variable X, but I don't think you need that. The only other thing you need is that p is a PDF. Nothing else in the paper is needed to evaluate that claim. Instead of me converting those 6-7 lines to LaTeX, one can glance at them and decide if they're clear enough.

Comment: One thing you could do is contact the authors by email. You could refer them to this site. They should be able to answer your question quickly.

Comment: Note that one of the paper's authors provided an answer. Also, the answer from JGWang clarifies it and is similar to the author's answer. @zhw's answer is correct given the way I stated the assumptions, which incorrectly neglected the fact that the claim doesn't necessarily apply (or it seems can't apply) to the supremum of points for which the assumptions hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the detailed proof of the integral $\int\limits_{p(x)>0} p^{-\lambda+1}(x) \| \ln p(x) \|^k dx$ is finite for any positive integer k under the assumption that

1. $0 < \lambda < \lambda^*$ where $\lambda^*$ is defined as $\sup\{ \lambda \geq 0 : \int p^{-\lambda+1}(x) dx < +\infty\}$
2. and $p(x)$ is a probability density function, i.e. $\int p(x) dx = 1$.

According to the definition of $\lambda^*$, for any $\lambda$ **strictly less than** $\lambda^*$, $\int p^{-\lambda+1}(x) dx < +\infty$.
Also, the claim $\int\limits_{p(x)>0} p^{-\lambda+1}(x) \| \ln p(x) \|^k dx$ is finite is only for any $\lambda$ **strictly less than** $\lambda^*$.

First, we can show that $B(\lambda) = \int\limits_{p(x) \geq 1} p^{-\lambda+1}(x) dx$ and $ C(\lambda) = \int\limits_{0 < p(x) < 1} p^{-\lambda+1}(x) dx$ are both finite for $0 < \lambda < \lambda^*$. Let $A (\lambda) = \int\limits_{p(x)>0} p^{-\lambda+1}(x) dx$ be a fintie number depending on $\lambda$.

$$ B(\lambda) + C(\lambda) = A(\lambda)$$
$$ 0 \leq B(\lambda) = \int\limits_{p(x) \geq 1} p^{-\lambda+1}(x) dx = \int\limits_{p(x) \geq 1} p^{-\lambda}(x) p(x) dx \leq \int\limits_{p(x) \geq 1} p(x) dx \leq \int\limits_{p(x) > 0} p(x) dx = 1$$

Therefore,

$$ A(\lambda)-1 \leq C(\lambda) \leq A(\lambda)$$

Now given a $\lambda$ and a $k$, notice that $\ln y \leq \frac{1}{\alpha} y^{\alpha}$ when $y \geq 1$ and $\ln 1/y \leq \frac{1}{\alpha} y^{-\alpha}$ when $0 < y < 1$ for any positive $\alpha$. First, let $\alpha = \frac{\lambda}{2k}$. Consequently,

\begin{align}
\int\limits_{p(x) \geq 1} p^{-\lambda+1}(x) \| \ln p(x) \|^k dx &\leq \int\limits_{p(x) \geq 1} p^{-\lambda+1}(x) \left( \frac{2k}{\lambda} \right)^k p^{\frac{\lambda}{2}}(x) dx \\ &= \left( \frac{2k}{\lambda} \right)^k \int\limits_{p(x) \geq 1} p^{-\frac{\lambda}{2}+1}(x) dx \\ &= \left( \frac{2k}{\lambda} \right)^k B(\lambda/2)
\end{align}

Then, let $\alpha = \frac{\lambda^* - \lambda}{2k}$,

\begin{align}
\int\limits_{0 < p(x) < 1} p^{-\lambda+1}(x) \| \ln p(x) \|^k dx &= \int\limits_{0 < p(x) < 1} p^{-\lambda+1}(x) \left( \frac{2k}{\lambda^* - \lambda} \right)^k \ln^{k} \frac{1}{p(x)} dx \\ &\leq \left( \frac{2k}{\lambda^* - \lambda} \right)^k \int\limits_{0 < p(x) < 1} p^{-\lambda+1}(x) p^{-\frac{\lambda^* - \lambda}{2}}(x) dx \\ &= \left( \frac{2k}{\lambda^* - \lambda} \right)^k \int\limits_{0 < p(x) < 1} p^{-\frac{\lambda^*+\lambda}{2}+1}(x) dx \\ &=  \left( \frac{2k}{\lambda^* - \lambda} \right)^k C \left(\frac{\lambda^*+\lambda}{2}\right)
\end{align}

Consequently,

$$\int\limits_{p(x)>0} p^{-\lambda+1}(x) \| \ln p(x) \|^k dx \leq \left( \frac{2k}{\lambda} \right)^k B(\lambda/2) + \left( \frac{2k}{\lambda^* - \lambda} \right)^k C\left(\frac{\lambda^*+\lambda}{2}\right)$$

Since $0 < \lambda < \lambda^*$, so are $\frac{\lambda}{2}$ and $\frac{\lambda^*+\lambda}{2}$, and therefore both $B(\lambda/2)$ and $C(\frac{\lambda^*+\lambda}{2})$ are finite. And the proof is finished.

Notice that the claim never mentions what whould happen if $\lambda = \lambda^*$. In fact, the counter example just shows that $\int\limits_{p(x)>0} p^{-\lambda+1}(x) \| \ln p(x) \|^k dx$ can be unbounded when $\lambda = \lambda^*$. Indeed, it can be shown that $\lambda^* = 2$ for $p(x)$ given by the counter example. To see that, just try to bound $\int\limits p^{-\lambda+1}(x) dx$ for any $\lambda > 2$ and you will see that no matter how close $\lambda$ is with $2$, $\int\limits p^{-\lambda+1}(x) dx$ is always unbounded.

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to answer. It definitely helps clarify and to point out where my confusion stemmed from. I wasn't careful to note that it wouldn't necessarily apply to the supremum point itself.

Comment: A correction is needed though. It is not necessarily true that $\ln y ≤ y^α$  when $y≥1$ for any positive $\alpha$. For example, consider $y = 500$ with $\alpha = 10^{-100}$. A constant that is dependent on $\alpha$ is needed as in @JGWang's answer.

Comment: You are right. It should be $\ln y < \frac{1}{\alpha} y^{\alpha}$.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: Define $p(x)= x(\ln x)^2$ in an interval $[0,b]$ for some small $b>0,$ constant on some $[b,c]$ so that $\int_0^c p(x)\,dx =1,$ and then is $0$ for other $x.$

Let $\lambda = 2, k =1.$ Then

$$\int_0^c p^{-1}(x)\, dx  = \int_0^b \frac{1}{x(\ln x)^2}\, dx + \int_b^c \frac{1}{p(b)}\, dx < \infty.$$

So $p$ satisfies the hypotheses. Claim:

$$ \int_0^{b} p(x)^{-1}\cdot |\ln p(x)|\,dx = \infty.$$

Indeed, the integrand is

$$\frac{|\ln x + 2\ln (|\ln x|)| }{x(\ln x)^2} \sim \frac{1}{x|\ln x|}$$
 near $0.$ That's a nonintegrable singularity, proving the claim.

---

Prvious incorrect answer: It doesn't look good: Take $p(x) = x, x \in (0,1), 0 $ elsewhere,  $\lambda = 2, k =1.$

Comment: Thank you @Winther, I did indeed so violate. Maybe I can fix it.

Comment: I fixed it (I think).

Comment: @Winther Why do you say that?

Comment: btw I also see that OP has added more conditions... which is always fun. However, I think this answers OPs original question. My 50 cents is that the statement in the paper is correct in some form (or another) when all conditions are correctly spelled out.

Comment: Those conditions changed after my comment; my new answer takes those into account. Agree on the 50 cent speculation.

Comment: So, this is information theory, where p(x) is always a probability mass function or probability density function satisfying either $\sum_x p(x) = 1$ or $\int p(x) \, dx = 1$, respectively, and probabilities are always between $0$ and $1$. So, no new info was added in my edit, other than to clarify that we're talking about a PDF not a CDF. All other assumptions are stated explicitly in one or two paragraphs of the paper around that equation. So, if we found a counterexample, I don't see how the statement in some form can be true ... Please clarify why you would think so.

Comment: probabilities are always between $[0,1]$ but probability density functions can be unbounded.

Comment: Okay. In that case, I suppose you can ignore the assumption that $p \in [0,1]$. Would that help in any way? The statement must be true for all $p$ and it seems you found a counterexample.

Comment: It doesn't really matter since my example has $p\in [0,1]$ anyway. If those are the assumptions in the paper, then we have a counterexample. Doubt arises since $1/(x(\ln x)^2)$ and its relatives are well known, certainly at the level of a paper in a decent journal. But I haven't checked the paper,.

Comment: Exactly -- your example satisfies the stronger assumption. If you have a moment, you can check out the paper, which spells out everything in literally a few lines from eq. 2.1 to 2.5. There's not much text there. The integrand in the paper has an extra denominator, which is a constant as far as I can tell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32640/discussion-between-sherif-f-and-zhw).

Comment: I moved to chat as the system prompted me to, and I put my responses there, but unfortunately, chat doesn't seem to display LaTeX for me. Feel free to comment here instead ...

Comment: Wanted to leave a comment here for the record explaining that this answer is indeed $\textit{correct}$ given the way I stated the assumptions. See comments on the original question and see other answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**1.** I would give an explanation about the following claim in the reference: *Under the assumption $\lambda^*(X)>0$, for any $\lambda\in (0,\lambda^*(X))$ and any positive (integer) $k$, the following integrals are finite,*
\begin{gather}
\int p^{-\lambda+1}(x)\,dx<\infty, \tag{1}\\
\int p^{-\lambda+1}(x)|\ln p(x)|^k\,dx<\infty \tag{2}
\end{gather}
According the definition of $\lambda^*(X)\triangleq \sup\{\lambda\ge 0:\int p^{-\lambda+1}(x)\,dx<\infty \}$, it suffices to prove that (2) is true.

Now we use following inequality (which can be derived from $1+y\le e^y$) , 
$$|\log p|^k\le\begin{cases}C_{k,\alpha}p^\alpha,\quad& p\ge 1,\\ C_{k,\alpha}\frac1{p^\alpha}, & 0<p<1.
\end{cases} \qquad k,\alpha >0 \tag{3}$$
where $C_{k,\alpha}$ is a constant depending on $k$ and $\alpha$(for example, $C_{k,\alpha}=(\frac{k}{\alpha e})^k$). For $\lambda\in (0,\lambda^*(X))$, there exists a $\lambda_2\in(\lambda, \lambda^*(X))$ such that
$$\int [p(x)]^{-\lambda_2+1}\,dx<\infty. \tag{4}$$ 
Meanwhile, using (3), we have
\begin{gather}
\int p^{-\lambda+1}(x)|\ln p(x)|^k1_{\{y:p(y)\ge1\}}(x)\,dx\le C_{k,\lambda}\int p(x)\,dx<\infty,\\
\int p^{-\lambda+1}(x)|\ln p(x)|^k1_{\{y:p(y)<1\}}(x)\,dx\le C_{k,\lambda_2-\lambda} \int [p(x)]^{-\lambda_2+1}\,dx<\infty,\\
\end{gather}
Now (2) is obtained from above inequalities.

**2.** To get $C_{k,\alpha}$:
\begin{align}
&1+y\le e^y,\quad \forall y\in\mathbb{R} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad x\le e^{x-1}=\frac1e e^x, \quad \forall x\in\mathbb{R}\\
\Rightarrow\quad & \frac{\alpha x}{k}\le \frac1e e^{(\alpha x)/k}\qquad
\Rightarrow\quad  \Bigl(\frac{\alpha x}{k}\Bigr)^k\le \frac1{e^k}e^{\alpha x},\quad \alpha,k,x>0\\
\Rightarrow\quad & x^k\le \Bigl(\frac{k}{\alpha e}\Bigr)^k e^{\alpha x},\quad \alpha,k,x>0 \qquad \Rightarrow\quad (3)
\end{align}

**3.**  The counterexample given by zhw in the previous answer  is **correctly** to provide an example to interpret the following claim couldn't be true:
$$
\left .\begin{matrix}\int_{p(x)>0}p(x)^{-\lambda+1}\,dx<\infty,\\
\lambda>0, k>0,\\
\int p(x)\,dx=1
\end{matrix}\right\} \Rightarrow\int_{p(x)>0}p^{-\lambda+1}(x)|\ln p(x)|^k\,dx<\infty. \tag{5}
$$
The (5) is different from the following statement: 
$$
\left .\begin{matrix}\int p(x)\,dx=1\\
\lambda_2>\lambda>0, k>0\\
\int_{p(x)>0}p(x)^{-\lambda_2+1},dx<\infty,
\end{matrix}\right\} \Rightarrow\int_{p(x)>0}p^{-\lambda+1}(x)|\ln p(x)|^k\,dx<\infty \tag{6}
$$
(6) is a claim derived from the reference and proved in the above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would you account for the counterexample given in the previous answer?

Comment: Also, can you show how you obtain $C_{k,\alpha}$ and thereby prove the inequality?

Comment: @Sherif Add some notes to reply your questions. If there is any question about it, please don't hesitate to tell me.

Comment: Thanks very much. It definitely helps to clarify and is similar to the answer provided here from the paper's author, which they provided upon my request. I think though that (5) isn't the claim that is not true. I think rather that the first statement on the left of the arrow in claim (5) should be $\int p^{-\lambda+1}(x) dx < \infty$ . Correct?

Comment: @Sherif Thank you! you are right, I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

You have not written down the condition correctly. Rather than
$$\int p^{\lambda-1}(x)dx<\infty$$
it should read
$$\int p^{\lambda^*-1}(x)dx<\infty\quad\text{for some }\lambda^*>\lambda.$$
These conditions are not equivalent, and in fact the statement in the paper is correct (as shown in other answers) whereas under your assumptions the statement is not correct (see the counterexample provided by zhw). Be careful with your assumptions.

Comment: This probably should be a comment rather than an answer. You're right that my assumptions might have not been correct. This was my interpretation based on the paper, which is I why I directed people to the paper. However, I don't think the reason you cited is the reason they're incorrect. $\lambda^*$ is the supremum of $\lambda \geq 0$ so that $\int p^{-\lambda+1}(x)dx < \infty$. Presumably then this is true for other $\lambda \in [0, \lambda^*)$. Right? In fact, see for example 2.4 in the paper, where it's explicitly stated that it hold for all such $\lambda$.

Comment: I think the problem is not that these inequalities don't hold in the assumptions. It's that even if they hold for a supremum $\lambda^*$, the claim to be proven doesn't necessarily hold for the same supremum point, but is only stated to hold for $\lambda < \lambda^*$.